# How to implement MSDOS style pattern matching (wildcards)?

Tags: c#

Is there any easy option to do MSDOS style pattern matching in C#?

I am very comfortable with RegEx; however, I need msdos style pattern matching.

Expected sample:

```
foo???.txt
*.bat
```

I think @zmbq's answer makes sense. I wanted to make sure that I am not missing any built-in feature in .NET. I guess I have to create an extension method Dos2RegExPattern that converts msdos patterns to regex and use it across my application.

Comment: What do you mean by "MSDOS style pattern matching"? Wild cards? Can you give a example of "MSDOS style pattern matching"?

Comment: I've edited the post to match answer (and it probably what you want). Feel free to edit again if you wanted something different.

Comment: Thank you Alexei, examples are good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the MS-DOS pattern to standard regular expression format. Change`?` to `.` and `*` to `.*`, and don't forget to escape other characters (`.` becomes `\.`).

So, for example, `*.bat` becomes `.*\.bat` and `file???.dat` becomes `file...\.dat` .

EDIT:

As @hvd pointed out in a comment, `?` in MS-DOS matches one or no characters, depending on its location (`file???.dat` matches all files with up to three characters after `file`, but `f?ile.dat` doesn't match `file.dat`). I doubt any of your users will notice that...

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the reverse.  Convert regex to dos.  Perhaps this says the same thing tho.

Comment: Was just about to post this same answer, but I'd replace * with its greedy version .*? instead

Comment: I surely hope not, the other way around is impossible, MS-DOS's patterns are weaker than regular expressions.

Comment: @BlackBear, maybe, if OP wants to match file-names then yes, otherwise I'm not sure it will be better.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used DOS, but I think `file???.dat` matches anywhere up to three characters after `file`, not exactly three.

Comment: @hvd - good catch! I just tried it and indeed - you're right. I'll edit.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't say it matches one or no characters. I think `f?ile.dat` doesn't match `file.dat`. But I don't remember the precise rules. :)

Comment: Oh dear, you're right again. I'll rephrase the edit and leave it as an exercise for OP...

Comment: Before I mark this as answer, I expect there is some DOS pattern matching in Powershell that can be used in C# as well. Does anyone know such feature in PowerShell?

Comment: If you want to apply the wild-card pattern to a directory, the .NET Directory class supports that already, and so does PowerShell. I couldn't find a PowerShell technique of applying this pattern to any string.

Comment: Don't forget to change . to \. for accuracy.

Answer (score -1):

In .Net, doesn't:-

```
Directory.GetFiles (path, pattern)
```

do exactly what the OP wants (see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx))?